# DNS Woes with Kali Linux

Tags: linux, debian, dns, kali-linux

I have Kali Linux configured with a static IP address. Detailed version information is shown below.

I cannot resolve hostnames. If I put nameserver IP addresses in /etc/resolv.conf, they get lost because that file (actually, the linked file /etc/resolv.conf points to) gets deleted on boot (even though resolvconf is not installed, as shown below). If I add nameserver IP addresses to /etc/network/interfaces via the "dns-nameservers" keyword, it seems they are simply ignored.

How may I properly configure name resolution services?

```
root@myHostname:~# uname -a
Linux myHostname 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1kali1 (2017-04-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@myHostname:~# cat /etc/debian_version
Kali Linux Rolling
root@myHostname:~# ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jul 15 18:32 /etc/resolv.conf -> /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
root@myHostname:~# ls -l /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
ls: cannot access '/var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf': No such file or directory
root@myHostname:~# dpkg --list | grep resolvconf
root@myHostname:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 172.25.100.2
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 172.25.100.1
   dns-search example.com
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
   address 192.168.101.2
   netmask 255.255.255.0
root@myHostname:~# nslookup example.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: I have tried from elsewhere on the same network, and names resolve fine. In fact, the Kali Linux machine my post is about was resolving fine when it had a dynamic IP address (DHCP). It was only when I switched over to a static IP address that I could not resolve names.

Comment: Which interface are you going out to the Internet on from this machine? `eth0` or `eth1`? Are you sure you are configuring the correct NIC you are going out to the Internet from on that machine?

Comment: eth0 is the intetface out to the Internet.

Comment: On my Kali VPS `/etc/resolv.conf` links to `/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf`. On yours does `resolv.conf` exist in `/run/NetworkManager` ? If so you should try adding your nameservers there and changing the `/etc/resolv.conf` softlink.